# rJava installation from local directory in windows

Tags: r, rjava

I installed R 2.11.1 and am running java 1.7.0

I downloaded the rJava source file rJava_0.8-8.zip from 
http://cran.us.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/2.11/

and ran install.packages("rJava_0.8-8.zip",repos=NULL,type="source") in R from the directory containing the file. But I am getting the following lines as error:

> Warning in install.packages("rJava_0.8-8.zip", repos = NULL, type = "source") :
>     argument 'lib' is missing: using 'C:\Users\Shiladitya\Documents/R/win64-library/2.11'
>
> Error in get(name, envir = asNamespace(pkg), inherits = FALSE) : 
>     object 'unpackPkgZip' not found
>
> Warning message:
>   In install.packages("rJava_0.8-8.zip", repos = NULL, type = "source") :
>     installation of package 'rJava_0.8-8.zip' had non-zero exit status

I'm being unable to install rJava the usual way by doing

> install.packages('rJava', .libPaths()[1], repos="http://cran.us.r-project.org")

since that is leading to an error message like this:

> Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.us.r-project.org/bin/windows64/contrib/2.11
>   Warning message:
>   In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
>     package ‘rJava’ is not available

Please help!

Comment: Is there any reason for you to install a 4 years old version of R?

Comment: Yeah :/ I was trying to use a software which had these requirements as prerequisites...not sure whether it would be compatible with newer versions.